# Notepad++ mysteriously rolled itself back, lost preferences and unsaved documents

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, data-recovery

I opened notepad++ today to find it reset to default settings, all custom preferences are reset (which is not such a problem) and dozens of unsaved tabs with important information are gone.

I immediately opened the backup directory at `%APPDATA%/Notepad++/backup` to find only 3 files, the latest of which is from 18th of April 2019... there should have been 50 to 100 files created as recently as yesterday.

Furthermore, the version of notepad seems to have rolled back to v8.4.8, a build from Dec 2022. I never go more than a week without updating npp.

The only thing that isn't reset are my plugins. This is extremely peculiar because it almost appeared as if an image of some parent directory had been restored, overwriting `%APPDATA%/Notepad++`. This is further supported by the fact that the files that did remain from 2019 were temporary files that I'd probably have closed anyway.

I have looked for alternative npp installations in case I had forgotten about one and that is what I've opened by mistake, but this is the only one on this machine.

Between sleeping my pc yesterday and finding npp reset today; I have not performed a disk cleanup or ran any kind of cleanup utilities, I have not installed any windows updates or new programs, nor have I had windows defender quarantine anything, in fact I haven't done anything I don't do on an almost daily basis on this machine.

I have pretty much accepted that these files are lost forever to the digital abyss, and yes I've learned my lesson... but the circumstances are just really weird here. Any help solving this mystery will be highly appreciated, if nothing else just so that it doesn't happen again.

I am using windows 10 and npp was installed using the 64bit installer with default configuration.

Comment: Have you asked [Notepad++ community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/)?

Comment: Just a hunch, but it could be that you have these files in your VirtualStore, and that somehow Windows is not using the VirtualStore anymore. VirtualStore location should be `%localappdata%\VirtualStore`. The idea behind this folder is to give users with non-admin rights write access by redirecting writes to the VirtualStore. Whenever read or write access is performed in the future, the VirtualStore folder is checked first, and if files are located there, they are used instead.

Comment: @MushyShaman: What is the folder where reside your files that were rolled back?

Comment: There are some disk cleanup tools, such as Wise Disk Cleaner and CCleaner, that can remove traces in applications. Regrettably, I recently accidentally removed LibreOffice templates, that way -- and had to restore them from a disk image.

Answer (score 0):

When you say rolled back I think version.

What it sounds like happened can be limited to the following scenarios:

1. either someone else opened notepad++ and closed a bunch of things and reset settings.
2. a software update which was poorly written propagated and didn't migrate the settings to whatever way they're being stored.

Those seem like the two biggest possibilities. I'm leaning towards the second likelihood if you don't share your pc.

The third which I consider unlikely, is some malicious piece of software altered the settings directory of the program. Why someone would write said software no idea, however one idea may be the theft of information.

I consider this to be unlikely.

Comment: Or the fourth most likely option, VirtualStore caused this.

Comment: now i'm really curious.  and this seems like a good thing to discuss visibly. what is virtual store and why might it malfunction this way ?  Using linux mostly these days.

Comment: @MysteriousMadCoder: Google is your friend.

Comment: @harrymc :P not really for my benefit although I do like discourse rather than cold dead post reading :P

Comment: This site is not intended for social discussion - it's only a Q & A site.

Comment: @harrymc why is there a chat feature then ? :P

Comment: @harrymc sometimes decent answers and including the specific pieces of information needed to solve a problem require interaction. and humans, actual humans need interaction to grow and learn more thoroughly. not consistent pointless drama and conflict and whatever else the present generation inflicts while secretly wishing to never have to speak to another human again it would seem.

Comment: "Chat" is for sweeping too-long exchanges under the carpet.

Comment: @harrymc well its for expansive interactions that get summarized in the end, sure.  but specifically i never heard of the technological piece you mentioned, its nice to hear a summary of its use you know rather than read 20 pages of tech documents for something i likely will never use or mess with. well. technically i have, the last time this question was posted and answered.

Comment: I placed a comment on the question explaining what a Virtual Store is.